# Cordova Starting Page Remote Url Fails

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

It's been a few years since i've done phone gap development. I'm doing an ionic app, and I recall that you could override the starting page ("index.html") to point to a remote host, in my case http://myserver/myapp by modifying the config.xml file:

```
<content src="http://myserver/myapp"/>
```

Does phone gap no longer support an extension less url as the source address? I've read posts that the url has to include .html. Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took some time to get it working but adding the following to the config.xml enabled the ability to set a remote start url:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://myserver">
```

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption is correct.

1. Apache cordova does't supports the ASP, MVC, JSP etc Domain Hosted
   Webpages as it runs and accesses resources of different mobile device.
2. Apache cordova supports pure HTML, CSS, Javascript which will work on cross device platform the ionic framework css renders differently based on the device type.

> Apache cordova uses the Html / Angular coding technologies in building
>   cross platform native application but not necessary use actual server
>   hosted web applications.

Comment: I've also tried to a remote host like http://myserver/myapp/index.html and that doesn't work either. The environment is IOS.